# How to search data from HTML and then scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find data in HTML with tag search input, when it is clicked to "find" it will scroll to where the data is placed.

```
$(function() {
    $('#searchBar').on('click', function(){
        if(searchBar.value == '.profiles'){
        var target = $('.profiles');
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name = reynaldo' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

That's the code I tried, please help me

Comment: It would be helpful to include a sample of your HTML as well.